# Sqoop import error

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to import a MySQL table using sqoop import. Following is the error that i am getting.

**Code:**

```
[root@sandbox ~]# sqoop import \
   --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db" \
   --username=root \
   --password=hadoop \
   --table departments \
   --as-avrodatafile \
  --target-dir=/user/root/departments
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: The connection property 'zeroDateTimeBehavior' acceptable values are: 'CONVERT_TO_NULL', 'EXCEPTION' or 'ROUND'. 
The value 'convertToNull' is not acceptable.

java.sql.SQLException: The connection property 'zeroDateTimeBehavior' acceptable values are: 'CONVERT_TO_NULL', 'EXCEPTION' or 'ROUND'.
The value 'convertToNull' is not acceptable.
```

Please help me out if anyone knows the reason/solution for this.

Thanks,
Rishi

Comment: I think the issue is related to handling of null values, Try setting below params...         --null-string '\\N' \
 --null-non-string '\\N' \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try using the following code below:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

Comment: This is how i tried it. Please correct me incase of any syntax error. However this code did not run as well.   [root@sandbox ~]#   sqoop import \
>   --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" \
>   --username=root \
>   --password=hadoop \
>   --table departments \
>   --as-avrodatafile \
>   --target-dir=/user/root/departments

Comment: you might want to try the following

`[root@sandbox ~]# sqoop import \
> --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=‌​round \
> --username root \
> --password hadoop \
> --table departments \
> --as-avrodatafile \
> --target-dir /user/root/departments`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Peter, the solution you mentioned here is accurate. For zeroDateTimeBehavior, the three acceptable values are CONVERT_TO_NULL,EXCEPTION or ROUND.  It was mentioned in the log clearly which i should have checked. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @RishiDeshmukh no worries pal.

Answer (score 2):

This how i tried and it worked for windows

```
sqoop import 
--connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL" 
--table tablename
--username username
--password password
--m 1 
--target-dir /user/sqoop/tablename
--outdir java_files
```

`zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL`  , the `CONVERT_TO_NULL` is driven from the error i got on run time . It works

Answer (score 0):

Works fine with "zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL"

Answer (score 0):

I got into the same issue after devops team upgraded the mysql to version 8. After that all the sqoop jobs started failing. I used below command and it worked for me.

```
sqoop import -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=queue --connect jdbc:mysql:/hostname:3306/db_name?zeroDateTimeBehavior=round -m 1 --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --username user --password pwd --table dim_store  --fields-terminated-by "\t" --hive-import --hive-overwrite  --hive-table hivedb.hivetable;
```